# The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When we run our flutter app we have an error that stop all, and the error don't say us where it comes from :

```
Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
vertical_stack_header_dialog.dart:61
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
text_theme.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `title` field on `TextTheme` is [removed in version 2.2](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/2-2-deprecations#texttheme). The replacement for it is `headline6`.

You need to replace

```dart
Theme.of(context).textTheme.title
```

with

```dart
Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6
```

---

This is the full list of the old and new APIs:

```
OLD         NEW

display4    headline1
display3    headline2
display2    headline3
display1    headline4
headline    headline5
title       headline6
subhead     subtitle1
body2       bodyText1
body1       bodyText2
subtitle    subtitle2
```

---

See also:

- [Deprecated API removed after v2.2](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/2-2-deprecations#texttheme)
- [TextTheme class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html)